# Google Spreadsheet Formula relating to dates

Tags: google-sheets

I need a formula that will do the following:

If cells in columns L, O or Q have a date of today or earlier then cell B must show the text "CHECK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `B2`, and copy it to where you need it:

```
=IF(OR(L2<=DATEVALUE(NOW()),O2<=DATEVALUE(NOW()),Q2<=DATEVALUE(NOW())),"CHECK","-")
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly, I've just realised I also need to factor this in too if possible: if cell f < or = 0

Comment: Maybe a spreadsheet tutorial would help, there are lots on the web. Also, please mark answers as correct.

Comment: I tried =if(or(f2<=(0),L2<=DATEVALUE(now()),O2<=DATEVALUE(now()),Q2<=DATEVALUE(now())),"CHECK","-"), that seems to work - thanks again for your help

Comment: Eddy, I checked your solution and found it to be not correct. Your solution shows in all cases the word `CHECK`. See the second sheet of the example file I prepared.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra it depends, it would fail your example, but not mine. As the OP does not provide an example, it is not possible to tell. But the OP did not report a problem, so I am guessing the solution I gave is fine. (Nice use of the Today() function, forgot they added that.)

Comment: First, the `OR` statement returns `TRUE` if the cell is empty. This would cause the logic to break, taking into account the three columns !! Secondly, the `OR` statement only returns `FALSE` if all of the conditions return `FALSE`. This is also not wanted by the OP !! Perhaps you can share a doc with us, and show us how it works on your side of the world?

Comment: Am sure you must be right. The OP did write "worked perfectly". There are lots more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following solution to accomplish that.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(              
   IF(                          // first IF statement
     IF(                        // second IF statement
       L:L<>"",L:L<=TODAY()
     ) +                        // boolean OR statement
     IF(                        // third IF statement
       O:O<>"",O:O<=TODAY()
     ) +                        // boolean OR statement 
     IF(                        // fourth IF statement
       Q:Q<>"",Q:Q<=TODAY()
   )=1, "CHECK","")
 )

Copy/paste
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(L:L<>"",L:L<=TODAY()) + IF(O:O<>"",O:O<=TODAY()) + IF(Q:Q<>"",Q:Q<=TODAY())=1,"CHECK",""))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Explained

The second, third and fourth IF statements return a `0` if the statement is `TRUE` and a `1` if the statement if `FALSE`.  The `+`'s in between act as a boolean operator `OR`. The first IF statement will validate the outcome of the three IF statements. The ARRAYFORMULA makes it possible to select column ranges, as you requested.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[IF statement with boolean OR](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEt5czVDbXNRRjA5V19yQzBqa1dpTFE&usp=sharing)**